# Not able to draw graph using jqplot in Android phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, jqplot

I am trying to draw a simple bar graph using jqplot in Android phonegap app but i am not getting anything, no error no graph.

I am new to jqplot and phonegap so please help me out.

my html file is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.jqplot.css" /> 

<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .myChart {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
</head>

   <body onload="init();">
<div data-role="page" id="page-home" class="type-interior" data-theme="b">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Bar Graph Demo</h1>
    </div>

<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">            
    <div id="barChart" class="myChart"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Index.js:

```
function init() {
//alert("hi");
}
$('#page-home').live('pageinit', function(event){       

        $.jqplot('barChart', [[[5,1], [3,3], [1,5]]], {
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                shadowAngle: 135,
                rendererOptions: {
                    barDirection: 'horizontal'
                },
                pointLabels: {show: true, formatString: '%d'}
            },
            axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                }
            }
        }).replot({clear: true, resetAxes:true});


});
```

Comment: Update: When i move graph plot code from pageinit to init function then it works but i dont want it in init().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

You should put your code in

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
    }
```

Also make sure that you have a div or any other html element with id 'barChart'.